# Can't find crontab definition

Tags: linux, debian, debian-buster

On a Debian 10 machine, `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` logs `CRON[455]: (root) CMD (/script.sh)`

But `crontab -e -u root` is empty.

Where can I find the definition of that crontab job for the root user?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

first, check if the cron job is defined for other users, then you can check the below file it may include some of the cron jobs

```
[root~]$ cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

Comment: thx, but there are no cron jobs for other users. and /etc/crontabs only includes cron.daily, cron.weekly etc.

Comment: can you check the files in `/ect/cron.d/*`

Comment: /ect/cron.d/* does not contain the definition

Comment: did you check all these files `cron.d/       cron.daily/   cron.deny     cron.hourly/  cron.monthly/ crontab       cron.weekly/`

Comment: sure, nothing relevant in there

Comment: are you running docker?

Comment: Try to enable cron job logs  to find out the source of the call (you need to edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and uncomment this line `
You can enable logging for cron jobs in order to track problems. You need to edit the /etc/rsyslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf (on Ubuntu) file and make sure you have the following line uncommented or add it if it is missing:

cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log`) . Then restart rsyslog and cron .  Debug logs will be here `/var/log/cron.log`